# Opening seperate windows in java, one being a graphic applet, the other being a interactive text field

Tags: java, applet, interactive, jgrasp

So I am relatively new to Java script and have had time to mess around a bit and seem to be struggling at a certain part. I have a project for my programming class and was assigned certain specifics, as my teacher doesn't want much, I would like some interactive parts in my program. I have tried scanner usage and always get a white screen with a text box only rather than the image my teacher wants to display, without the said scanner line I can have the text box and graphic but do not get interaction.

So far I have got just the image showing, being a person with simple scenery, and a text box that is commented out; my question is how can I get the text box to take user input and assign variables to change the image and math that is there?

Thankyou for the help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.Console;

public class Project extends Applet// implements ActionListener
{

/*TextField inputLine = new TextField(50);  

public Project() {
    add(inputLine);
    inputLine.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
//Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = inputLine.getText();
    String sUp = s.toUpperCase();
    inputLine.setText(sUp);


 */ // double X = user_input.nextInt();




public void paint(Graphics g)
{

//Foreground
setForeground(Color.green);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,0,0,1000,1000);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.lightBlue);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,0,0,1000,200);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);
//Variables
double X = 10;
double Y = 15;
double Z = X + Y;
//Drawn Words
Expo.drawString(g,"Brenden Noonen",10,20); //Heading

//Hair
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.gold);
Expo.fillArc(g,500,50,55,30,0,360);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);
//Math
Expo.drawString(g,"Math: X + Y = Z",10,40);
Expo.drawString(g,"X: 10, Y: 15",10,60);
Expo.drawString(g,X + Y + "=" + Z,10,80);
Expo.drawString(g,"Answer: " + Z,10,100);

//Filled Rectangles Neck
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.lightTan);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,475,75,525,200);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);
//Expo.drawRoundedRect(g,325,500,675,1000);


//Drawn Rectangles Neck
Expo.drawRectangle(g,475,75,525,200);
//Drawn Circles
//Expo.drawCircle(g,500,325,150);

//Filled Circles
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.lightTan);

Expo.fillCircle(g,500,75,50); //Face Fill

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);

Expo.fillCircle(g,475,65,5); //Eyes
Expo.fillCircle(g,525,65,5);

//Expo.fillCircle(g,440,265,10); 

Expo.drawCircle(g,500,75,50); //Face Outline

//Drawn Rectangles
Expo.drawRectangle(g,25,550,50,575);

//Filled Rectangles
Expo.fillRectangle(g,75,550,100,575);

//Drawn Circles
Expo.drawCircle(g,125,562,12);

//Filled Circles
Expo.fillCircle(g,165,562,12);

//Drawn Arcs
Expo.drawArc(g,500,95,15,10,90,270); //Mouth
Expo.drawArc(g,475,55,10,5,280,80); //Eyebrows
Expo.drawArc(g,525,55,10,5,280,80);
Expo.drawArc(g,500,80,5,12,60,130);//Nose

//Filled Arcs
//Expo.setColor(g,Expo.lightGray);
//Expo.fillArc(g,440,255,15,15,120,240);

//Drawn Ovals

//Filled Ovals
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.lightGray);
Expo.fillOval(g,475,68,4,2); //Eyes color
Expo.fillOval(g,525,68,4,2);

//Shirt
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);
Expo.fillOval(g,500,175,75,30); //shoulders


Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);
Expo.drawOval(g,500,175,75,30); //top outline

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,440,175,560,300); //shirt
Expo.fillRectangle(g,440,175,425,220); //arm sides
Expo.fillRectangle(g,560,175,575,220);

//Arms
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.tan);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,428,220,438,380);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,563,220,573,380);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);

//Hair Top
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.gold);
Expo.fillArc(g,500,30,55,15,0,360);

//Jeans
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.darkBlue);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,440,301,560,560);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,440,540,560,560);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.green);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,480,360,520,1000);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.bronze);

//House
Expo.fillRectangle(g,875,150,975,250); //House base
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);
Expo.drawRectangle(g,875,150,975,250);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.bronze);
Expo.fillPolygon(g,875,150,925,75,975,150); //Roof
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);
Expo.drawPolygon(g,875,150,925,75,975,150);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.yellow);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,925,175,950,200);
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);
Expo.drawRectangle(g,925,175,950,200);

//Trees
Expo.setColor(g,Expo.brown);
Expo.fillRectangle(g,225,275,275,125);

Expo.setColor(g,Expo.darkGreen);
Expo.fillCircle(g,250,75,65);
}
}
```

Comment: Important point: "Java" != "JavaScript".  Two completely separate things, with practically *nothing* in common but the name...  Q: How can I get the text box to take input?  A: Generally *not* from "System.in". Instead, you'll probably need an "Action Listener". Look here: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jtextfield-basic-tutorial-and-examples

Comment: I had tried Action Listener but it created the white screen too.